# Вернуться на прошлый tabpage c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть несколько tabpage, на которые мы переходим в зависимости от выбранного варианта. Мне нужно, чтобы из текущего tabpage мы могли вернуться на предыдущий(грубо говоря запомнить его), проблема в том, что в текущий мы можем перейти из нескольких tabpage и вернуться мы должны именно на предыдущий. Как это реализовать? Реализован переход, а вот выход нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У TabControl есть событие `Deselected`, которое решает все Ваши проблемы. Я думаю лучшим объяснением будет пример ниже:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
          /....

          int oldTabIndex;  // Переменная в которой хранится старый индекс выбранной страницы

          //На событие Deselected средствами конструктора форм вешаем обработчик
          private void tabControl1_Deselected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e)
          { 
                 //Запоминаем текущий индекс страницы, перед его изменением
                 oldTabIndex = tabControl1.SelectedIndex;
          }

          //Демонстрация возврата на ранее выбранную страницу 
          private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
                tabControl1.SelectedIndex = oldTabIndex;
          }

          //............. 

    }
```

Если, что не понятно - спрашивайте.